# Destination array was not long enough in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to store an image in the database.
Here is my code

`Create.cshtml` view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post,new { @class = "form-horizontal",enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Photo, new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Photo, new { @class = "form-control-file", @type="file",@name="Photo" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
            Save
        </button>
    </div>
}
```

Model class:

```
public string Photo { get; set; }
```

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult Create(Student s)
{
            if (Request.Files.Count >= 1)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[0];
                var ImgBytes = new Byte[file.ContentLength - 1];

                // error occurs here
                file.InputStream.Read(ImgBytes, 0,file.ContentLength); 
                var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(ImgBytes, 0, ImgBytes.Length);
                s.Photo = base64String;
            }

            db.Students.Add(s);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return View();
        }
```

When I run this code I get the following error

> The destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

Either you're used to writing VB code or you read a VB example somewhere. In VB, you use the upper bound when creating an array, i.e. if you want an array with N elements then you specify N-1 when creating the array, e.g.

```vb
'Create an array of 100 things.
Dim things = New Thing(99) {}
```

In C#, you specify the length when creating an array, e.g.

```cs
// Create an array of 100 things.
var things = new Thing[100];
```

You are explicitly creating an array with one too few elements here by subtracting 1 from the length:

```cs
var ImgBytes = new Byte[file.ContentLength - 1];
```

Comment: Here I am creating an array of lengths equal to the size of the bytes of an image. I have watched this from a video tutorial. For the Instructor, it is working fine but for me it throwing this error.